# Finding the closest interpreted point in GeoDistance

Tags: geography, distance

I'd like to know how far away I am standing from the path of totality for the 2024 solar eclipse.

```
loc = GeoPosition[{43.215580, -77.937510}];
eclipse = 
  SolarEclipse[{DateObject[{2024, 4, 8, 0, 0}]}, 
   "TotalPhaseCenterLine", EclipseType -> "Total"];
bport = Entity["City", {"Brockport", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}];
GeoGraphics[{
  GeoMarker[loc],
  eclipse},
 GeoCenter -> bport,
 GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Miles"]]
```

[image]

```
GeoDistance[loc, First@eclipse["Values"]]
(* 0.735... miles *)
```

That seems about right. Now, I would like to know the `GeoPosition` of that point. The problem is, the solar eclipse data is (in this case) ~ 195 points, and the closest data point is actually 19 miles away.

```
minpt = GeoPosition@
  With[{pts = GeoDistance[loc, #] & /@ eclipse["Values"][[1, 1, 1]]},
   (*Position[pts,Min@pts]*)
   eclipse["Values"][[1, 1, 1, Position[pts, Min@pts][[1, 1]]]]]
GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[{loc, minpt}], PlotLabel -> GeoDistance[loc, minpt]]
```

[image]

It is nice that `GeoDistance` is interpolating the eclipse line. Do I have to do the same in order to figure out the point on the solar eclipse path that is closest to my current location? I thought perhaps one could use `GeoDirection` along with `GeoDestination` however the former does not accept the eclipse path as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

We can binary search for the nearest point.

First we find our initial search bracket:

```
dists0 = Normal[GeoDistance[loc, eclipse["Values"][[1, 1]]]];

i1 = Ordering[QuantityMagnitude[dists0, "Miles"], {1}][[1]];
i2 = Which[
  i1 === 1, 2,
  i1 === Length[dists0], i1-1,
  dists0[[i1 + 1]] < dists0[[i1 - 1]], i1 + 1, 
  True, i1 - 1
];

{p1, p2} = Thread[eclipse["Values"][[1, 1]]][[{i1, i2}]];
```

Next define the binary search function:

```
BinarySearch[f_, l_, h_, distf_, meanf_, tol_] :=
  Block[{lo = l, hi = h, mid},
    While[distf[lo, hi] > tol,
      mid = meanf[lo, hi];
      If[TrueQ[f[lo, hi, mid]], hi = mid, lo = mid]
    ];
    lo
  ]
```

Then our custom functions:

```
bfunc = GeoDistance[loc, #1] < GeoDistance[loc, #2]&;

mfunc = GeoPosition[Mean[{#1[[1]], #2[[1]]}]]&;

dfunc = GeoDistance;
```

Then run:

```
pmin = BinarySearch[bfunc, p1, p2, dfunc, mfunc, Quantity[10^-9.0, "Meters"]]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{43.205, -77.930}]
> ```

Visualize:

```
GeoGraphics[
  {GeoMarker[loc], eclipse, GeoMarker[pmin, "Color" -> Blue]},
  GeoCenter -> bport, 
  GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Miles"]
]
```

[image]

If the path of totality was returned as a `GeoPath` instead of `Line` we would need to replace `mfunc` to ensure the midpoint remains on the path. Something like this:

```
mfunc2 = GeoDestination[#1, GeoDisplacement[{0.5GeoDistance[##], GeoDirection[##]}]]&;
```

---

Now, note that `pmin` is farther away than what `GeoDistance` gives us for the path:

```
GeoDistance[loc, eclipse["Values"][[1]]]
```

> ```
> 0.735... miles
> ```

```
GeoDistance[loc, pmin]
```

> ```
> 0.785... miles
> ```

However the distance reported by `pmin` looks correct:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[loc], eclipse,
  {Red, GeoCircle[loc, GeoDistance[loc, eclipse["Values"][[1]]]]},
  {Blue, GeoCircle[loc, GeoDistance[loc, pmin]]}}, 
  GeoCenter -> bport, 
  GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Miles"]
]
```

[image]

What's happening is `GeoDistance` is treating the path as a `GeoPath`, whereas `GeoGraphics` is staying true to `Line`. If we work with geodesics across the board we can fix the discrepancy:

```
pmin2 = BinarySearch[bfunc, p1, p2, dfunc, mfunc2, Quantity[10^-9.0, "Meters"]]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{43.2061, -77.9308}]
> ```

```
GeoDistance[loc, pmin2]
```

> ```
> 0.735... miles
> ```

Replacing `Line` with `GeoPath` in the graphic:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[loc], GeoPath @@ eclipse["Values"][[1]],
  {Blue, GeoCircle[loc, GeoDistance[loc, pmin2]]}}, 
  GeoCenter -> bport, 
  GeoRange -> Quantity[2, "Miles"]
]
```

[image]

---

Lastly, a completely different approach is to numerically solve for where the relevant `GeoCircle` and the path of totality intersect. The advantage here is we don't need to scrutinize the 'path type' of our curve.

```
path = eclipse["Values"][[1]];

d = GeoDistance[loc, path];

distα[α_?NumericQ] :=
  QuantityMagnitude[
    GeoDistance[GeoDestination[loc, GeoDisplacement[{d, α}]], path], 
    "Miles"
  ]

αmin = α /. FindRoot[distα[α], {α, 150, 0, 360}];
pmin3 = GeoDestination[loc, GeoDisplacement[{d, αmin}]]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{43.2061, -77.9307}]
> ```

```
GeoDistance[loc, pmin3]
```

> ```
> 0.735... miles
> ```

Comment: Excellent - thanks much for explaining the GeoPath/Line discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use `Projection`.

```
near = Nearest[GeoPosition /@ eclipse["Values"][[1, 1, 1]], loc, 2] /. 
  GeoPosition[pt_] :> pt
ptonline = 
 Projection[loc["LatitudeLongitude"] - First@near, 
    Normalize@Flatten@Differences@near] + First@near // GeoPosition
GeoGraphics[{GeoMarker[loc], eclipse, GeoMarker[ptonline]}, 
 GeoCenter -> bport, GeoRange -> Quantity[1, "Miles"]]
GeoDistance[loc, ptonline]
```

[image]

Although note that `GeoDistance[loc,ptonline]` gives a slightly longer distance (0.80 mi vs 0.735) which might be due to working with vectors on a sphere. That math is well beyond me.